# seaborn\matplotlib\pandas plot not showing ylabel

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm trying to create a violin plot for some data, but for some reason my ylabel won't change.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
ax.set_title('Violin plots for fat content per lab', size=18, weight='bold')
ax.set_ylabel('Fat content (%)')

sns.violinplot(data=df_eggs, x='Lab', y='Fat_Content', ax=ax);
```

I'm using Jupyter Notebook and I imported pandas, seaborn and matplotlib beforehand.
Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4vIn.png).

Comment: The label changes: First it's `'Fat content (%)'`, but then you change it via the violinplot to `'Fat_Content'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commentor is right. Just change the order of things like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
ax.set_title('Violin plots for fat content per lab', size=18, weight='bold')
sns.violinplot(data=df_eggs, x='Lab', y='Fat_Content', ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel('Fat content (%)')
```

When you put the `ax.set_ylabel` before the `sns.violinplot`, the label you set with the `ax.set_ylabel` is being overwritten with the y label written by the `sns.violinplot`.